# Row_number() returns null value how to solve this unexpected problem

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, row-number, sql-server-2017

Here the SQL query

```
;WITH rankedresults AS 
(
    SELECT 
        userid, 
        rowid 
    FROM   
        (SELECT 
             userid, 
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY referredplayercount DESC) AS RowId 
         FROM   
             tblusersprofile) dt 
    WHERE  
         rowid BETWEEN 1 AND 50
) 
SELECT 
    tblusersprofile.userid, 
    referredplayercount, 
    username, 
    avatarimagelink, 
    authoritylevel, 
    rowid 
FROM
    tblusersprofile 
LEFT JOIN 
    rankedresults ON tblusersprofile.userid = rankedresults.userid 
WHERE  
    tblusersprofile.userid IN (SELECT rankedresults.userid 
                               FROM rankedresults) 
    AND referredplayercount > 0 
ORDER BY 
    rowid ASC
```

Here the returned results which is not expected to have null row number

[image]

I wonder that is `rankedresults` re-generated with this query again?

```
SELECT rankedresults.userid 
FROM rankedresults
```

Comment: Is the `rowid` between 1 and 50 when ordering by referredplayercount desc? (Note: You may want to add the `WHERE userid IN (select userid from rankedresults)` to the CTE.)

Comment: @ZLK it is 1-49 instead of 1-50

Comment: I think you may be confused... The window function in the CTE checks the order against the ENTIRE table regardless of your filter on the outer query... I think you should get rid of the CTE/join and just put the window function on the outer query...

Comment: So for example `SELECT *, rowid = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY referredplayercount DESC) FROM mytable WHERE userID in (...) etc etc;`

Comment: @ZLK i am very confused here. the CTE query returns 50 results exaclty when i run it alone. however even though i have where clause how can i get null value or lesser than 50 results when used inner join instead of left join

Comment: So your CTE is selecting from the whole table, but your outer query is filtering out things based on what exists in another table. Think of it like this... I have the letters A, B, C, D, E and I assign a row number to each of them (1, 2, 3, 4, 5). But I only select those with a rowID BETWEEN 1 AND 3 so just A, B, C. Later I select every second letter from the table (A, C, E) and left join to my rowIDs (1, 2, 3). But E doesn't have a rowID because it wasn't between 1 and 3...

Comment: @ZLK you are mistaken. there is where clause did you check it carefully? WHERE  
    tblusersprofile.userid IN (SELECT rankedresults.userid 
                               FROM rankedresults)

Comment: Oh, never mind, I see that you're doing something weird here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Userid is 1137 is only in the tbluserprofile table, and not in the rankedresults CTE.

Because it's a LEFT JOIN, since there's no match, the rowid in the result shows as NULL.

The row_number() function itself can't generate NULL's.

But to make sure that the ROW_NUMBER in the CTE always returns the exact same order, add the userid in the ORDER BY

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY referredplayercount DESC, userid) AS RowId
```

But perhaps you could avoid using that CTE twice?

```
;WITH rankedresults AS 
(
    SELECT 
     userid, 
     RowId
    FROM
    (
       SELECT 
        userid, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY referredplayercount DESC, userid ASC) AS RowId 
       FROM tblusersprofile
       WHERE referredplayercount > 0 
    ) dt
    WHERE RowId BETWEEN 1 AND 50
) 
SELECT 
    usrprof.userid, 
    usrprof.referredplayercount, 
    usrprof.username, 
    usrprof.avatarimagelink, 
    usrprof.authoritylevel, 
    rr.rowid 
FROM
    tblusersprofile usrprof
JOIN 
    rankedresults rr ON rr.userid = usrprof.userid
ORDER BY 
    rr.RowId ASC
```

And if you can use [OFFSET & FETCH](http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-offset-fetch/), and you don't really need that RowId in the select?
Then you might not even need a CTE with a row_number to page the results.

```
declare @offsetrows int = 0;
declare @nextrows int = 50;

SELECT 
 userid, 
 referredplayercount, 
 username, 
 avatarimagelink, 
 authoritylevel
FROM tblusersprofile
WHERE referredplayercount > 0
ORDER BY referredplayercount DESC, userid ASC
OFFSET @offsetrows ROWS FETCH NEXT @nextrows ROWS ONLY;
```

Simplified tests on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3aaad57fc7b1d20704fa90f4a9d4b6ed)*

Comment: it should not be because it selects userid only in rankedresults. WHERE  tblusersprofile.userid IN (SELECT rankedresults.userid 
                                  FROM   rankedresults)

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG He is obviously right. You may easily test is by running the CTE. You loose the userid 1137 when applying the `rowid BETWEEN 1 AND 50` condition

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG If you are sure, then replace the `LEFT JOIN` for a simple `JOIN`.

Comment: Well, ok, hadn't looked at the WHERE clause. Hmm, odd.  But still, why use that IN when just the INNER JOIN would suffice.

Comment: @LukStorms inner join doesnt solve the problem either. yes no null values but it has to have 50 elements but it is having 48

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG Ok, I might have a hunch, although I don't exactly know how to reproduce it.  The thing is, I've seen in another post some time ago that MS Sql Server sometimes in the execution plan treats a CTE like a template.  Therefor it could run the CTE twice if it's used twice.  If that missing userid in the first 50 of the first run of the CTE, but is there in the second? Then that would explain that NULL rowid.

Comment: @LukStorms yep that is also what comes to my mind. how can i prevent that?

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG Easy I think. Just make sure that the row_number always gives the exact same order.  Include the userid in it.  `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY referredplayercount DESC, userid) AS RowId `

Comment: @LukStorms yep such addition fixed the issue. so is this a bug or something?

Comment: Not a bug, it's more a feature ;)  It's just how Microsoft written the Query Optimizer to deal with Common Table Expressions in MS Sql Server.  But this is the first time I see it have such effect.  Probably there are userid close to the rowid = 50 that have the same referredplayercount.  You could run the query of that CTE for the first 60 to check if that's the case.

Comment: Is there a reason why you just don't use select top 50,and order by referredplayercount desc? Why the cte?

Comment: @SørenKongstad this is how you do paging. There is no other way as far as i know. you know splitting results into pages.

Comment: @LukStorms no there were same referredplayercount having rows that is why the results were not deterministic. so dual run of CTE resulted different results

Comment: @LukStorms: Wow, that's a big "feature", but only in Newspeak :-( According to Standard SQL the result of a CTE must be the same when accessed multiple time...

Comment: It's a developer's inside joke sometimes.  When someone complains about what they think is a bug. "Nah, it's a feature!". Although in some cases it really was intended for specific reasons (that are different from the user)

Comment: I know, (not only) MS tends to ignore such things ("works as designed/implemented") even if it's plain wrong :-(

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG Oh you are going for paging. The question was not about paging however. Since I think SQL Server 2012, there has been a method for paging, that is offset and fetch, as can bee seen in the accepted answer.